# WindowLeaked on AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I got WindowLeaks on my `AsyncTask` and I dont know how to deal with it I even tried putting a `dismiss()` on it on the `onPostExecute` but its still giving me the same problem.

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    if(this.showLoadingMessage) {
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
        this.progressDialog.setMessage(this.loadingMessage);
        this.progressDialog.show();
        this.progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    }
    super.onPreExecute();
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(this.showLoadingMessage && this.progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    result = result.trim();
    if(this.asyncResponse != null) {
        this.asyncResponse.processFinish(result);
    }

    if(this.exception != null) {
        if(this.exceptionHandler != null) {
            this.exceptionHandler.handleException(this.exception);
        }

        if(this.eachExceptionsHandler != null) {
            Log.d(this.LOG, "" + this.exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
            if(this.exception instanceof MalformedURLException) {
                this.eachExceptionsHandler.handleMalformedURLException((MalformedURLException)this.exception);
            } else if(this.exception instanceof ProtocolException) {
                this.eachExceptionsHandler.handleProtocolException((ProtocolException)this.exception);
            } else if(this.exception instanceof UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                this.eachExceptionsHandler.handleUnsupportedEncodingException((UnsupportedEncodingException)this.exception);
            } else if(this.exception instanceof IOException) {
                this.eachExceptionsHandler.handleIOException((IOException)this.exception);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

this leaks occur when this codes are working.

```
                                        HashMap postNotification = new HashMap();

                                    postNotification.put("txtOwner", tvRenter.getText().toString());

                                    AsyncClass taskCount = new AsyncClass(ownerAccept.this, postNotification, new AsyncResponse() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void processFinish(String s) {
                                            if(s.contains("success")){
                                                HashMap postNotif = new HashMap();

                                                postNotif.put("txtOwner", tvRenter.getText().toString());

                                                AsyncClass taskAdd = new AsyncClass(ownerAccept.this, postNotif, new AsyncResponse() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void processFinish(String s) {
                                                        if(s.contains("success")){
                                                            Log.d(TAG, s);
                                                            Intent in = new Intent(ownerAccept.this, RenterTabs.class);
                                                            startActivity(in);
                                                            finish();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                                    taskAdd.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/notificationAccept.php");
                                            } else {
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    taskCount.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/carkila/notificationCount.php");
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = a_accept.create();
                    alert.setTitle("Accept");
                    alert.show();
```

Comment: Where is the `context` from? If you're ending the `Activity` that supplies the `context` you're going to end up with a leak.

Comment: Can you post your `LogCat`? it seems you're executing a new task in the callback of your first one which seems to be causing your issue since you're showing a new `Dialog` without dismissing the old one and then finishing the activity.

Answer (score 0):

When do you have these leaks? Remember that if activity (or fragment) where you start AsyncTask is destroyed, these leaks will occur.

Comment: Added the activity that have leaks sir.

Comment: You can avoid this by migrating your AsyncTasks to IntentServices. The AsyncTask relies on the activity or fragment to live, if they are destroyed because of memory problems or other reason you will get WindowLeaks. I recommend you to read Android's guide of Services https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. It is more code to write, but it is rewarding at the end.

Comment: +JosephG can you show the full stack trace, the problem might also be the way your are presenting the dialog.